# JQUERY - disabling href scroll but not appending the URL?

Tags: jquery

I have some links that have the `href` property halfway down my page. What I have been trying to do is stop the browser from changing the vertical position of the page but still append the `#myHREF` to the url?

I have tried `return false;` and `event.preventDefault();` but they both stop the page from moving vertically but also from assigning the anchor the url.

I know it is possible but just not sure how!?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a hashchange plugin like this one: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: Hash changes still trigger the scrolling behavior.

Comment: Not quite, have a look at http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/

Comment: That page doesn't have any DOM elements associated with the hash values. It wouldn't scroll anyway :)

Comment: I assume the OP has arranged his DOM in a similar fashion. Otherwise it's going to be a pain to manage all that scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is to implement a hack that scrolls the window to the top on each click. There's some discussion about it in this SO thread:

[Prevent/stop auto anchor link from occurring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703530/prevent-stop-auto-anchor-link-from-occurring)